# Express JS Keep Session Alive On restart

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to restart and keep the session alive using nodemon, but when you restart the session is destroyed.. I wonder if there is any way to keep living with nodemon or other node js library session.

> scripts ": {
>        // "Start": "node ./bin/www"
>        "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
>       }

Thanks for your time

Comment: What Session are you talking about? A User-Session? If so, you will need a external Session-Storage - can be any Database, for example MongoDB .

Comment: Assuming you mean a user session module for an HTTP server, you'll need to use persistent storage, such as a database. If you're using [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), you can configure this via the [`store` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#store). There are [numerous packages available](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=express+session) for it, depending on the specific database you want to use.

Answer (score 5):

In order to persist session, there are two approaches:

1. **Use some persistent store**
2. **Use JSON Web Tokens**

For implementing **persistent session**, you can use MongoDB session store or Redis Session store.

If you want to use redis then make use of [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) npm package.
If you want to use MongoDb as session store then make use of [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) npm package

There are some settings which you need to do in you app.js/server.js. In one of my demo i am using Redis Session store with PassportJS, if you are looking for example, feel free to look [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-passport-auth).

If you want to use **JSON web tokens**, there are many different implementations available.
I am using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). I implemented this using PassportJS, ExpressJS and AngularJS in front End. For example look [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-jwt-auth).
Tokens are encoded and stored in browser's local storage with a secret key.

I would suggest you to go for JSON web tokens, read it in detail because that is how most of the major web apps are developed. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: can you please tel me in jwt approach how you persist sessions i mean you have to store them somewhere ??

Comment: You can store it is browser's local storage when user sign in and delete it when user logout. When ever users visits the URL then check if session is valid. Also one important case is passing token for every back end API calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your session is only good until the process dies. Then it is destroyed. You must use a persistent storage mechanism or a simple solution is to use:

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session

May not be a good long term solution but will help you get started.